# Fastboot freezes on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: fastboot, terminal, command-line, macos

I just got a new MacBook 2016 with Mac OS Sierra installed, after setting up my complete development environment and all required tools via Android Studio, I tried to flash a new Android Wear release on my watch.

ADB is working without issues, but as soon as I try to run any `fastboot` command (other than `fastboot help`) it will completely freeze and never finish.

It is just stuck with no output at all.

I already tried to run it with `sudo` or reinstall it via the SDK Manager, I also tried different standalone `fastboot` binaries provided on XDA developers.

There is nothing which seems to make it finish. Even "ctrl + c" won't exit the running command. Only killing it via the process list will work.

Comment: Did you setup all drivers? When fastboot "freezes" it's because the device is not detected. I never tried on Mac but on Windows it shows  `Waiting for device`

Comment: It won't even show this output. So everything is installed. Tools all dependencies. (adb working without issues)

Comment: How do you get in Fastboot mode?

Comment: @esQmo I have installed the tools on my pc and added the `tools` folder to the path variable. so I just type "fastboot devices" and it won't output anything. The device was set to fastboot by doing "adb reboot bootloader" (also tried with other devices) the thing is that fastboot won't output anything at all, no warning that it's waiting for a device, nor anything else

Comment: Did you follow the step by step instructions like these from here ? http://www.stechguide.com/setup-adb-and-fastboot-on-mac-easy-step-by-step-guide/

Comment: Yes I did. I used tried these files too

Comment: Weird... What phone model is that?

Comment: I am very sure its not about the phone or watch. But some issue with fastboot on mac OS. as it won't finish the command at all or won't quit if I do "ctrl + c"

Comment: Oh my bad, you said a watch... May be an issue with MAC though. Try it with a Windows computer. Can't help further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this was an official Android fastboot bug. They are currently testing a fix in their QA department.

With the new platform tools release it will be fixed:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231129

Answer (score 2):

Not really a solution but a workaround:
I've been having the same issue without finding anything online. Am using a 2016 Macbook Pro, Nexus 4 and a USB A to micro USB cable with an A-to-C adaptor.

I used Parallels to run a virtual Ubuntu machine and installed `fastboot` there (as per [here](http://lifehacker.com/the-easiest-way-to-install-androids-adb-and-fastboot-to-1586992378) to minimize storage usage). When I plug my phone in I tell Parallels to connect it to the virtual machine. Not ideal, but at least I can use `fastboot`!

Comment: oh interesting. So it seems the new MacBook or USB Type C (Thunderbolt 3) is somehow incompatible with `fastboot`. I wonder why there is no bug report for the android tools, nor anywhere else open yet.

Comment: Running into the same issue on a new Macbook Pro 2016 and the latest version of fastboot with a Nexus 6p. I have tried the Apple usb-c to usb-a adapter and even a straight usb-c to usb-c cable. It just hangs.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's definitely a MacBook USB/Thunderbolt issue. Surprised I haven't seen more information about it. We can't be the only two with the new MacBook trying to use `fastboot`!

Comment: Just asked a colleague of mine to test this too. He was also able to reproduce it

Comment: Can also confirm this issue on a 13 inch MacBook Pro 2016 model, fastboot from homebrew and a OnePlus 3 device.

Comment: I can also confirm the issue on 15 inch MBP 2016

Comment: Not sure if anyone sees the same symptoms but recently I've noticed some more strange behavior. I load Ubuntu in Parallels 12, use `fastboot` as needed and then when I disconnect the device my Touch Bar is frozen until I reboot my Macbook and my Macbook won't detect my Android device until I reboot. Maybe the issue is related to the Touch Bar?

Answer (score 2):

Google has released an update to [**Android Platform Tools**](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html) that fixes this. You can use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) to install the latest version:

```
brew update
brew install android-platform-tools
```

---

Once you update to revision `25.0.4` or above, `fastboot` will no longer hang on Macbook Pro 2016 / MacOS Sierra. From its changelog:

> ### [25.0.4 (March 16, 2017)](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html)
>
> - Added experimental `libusb` support to Linux and Mac `adb`
>
> To use the `libusb` backend, set the environment variable
>   `ADB_LIBUSB=true` before launching a new `adb server`. The new `adb host-features` command will tell you whether or not you're using `libusb`.
>
> To restart adb with libusb and check that it worked, use
>
> ```
> adb kill-server; ADB_LIBUSB=1 adb start-server; adb host-features`
> ```
>
> The output should include "libusb".
>
> In this release, the old non-libusb implementation remains the
>   default.
>
> - `fastboot` doesn't hang 2016 MacBook Pros anymore ([bug 231129](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231129))
> - Fixed Systrace command line capture on Mac

Answer (score 0):

Similar symptoms, different versions. On a Macbook Air M1, with a phone connected over USB-C, `adb` worked fine for me but `fastboot` (34.0.0 from Homebrew) just hung there (though in my case <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> worked).

[The solution for me was to plug the device in a different port](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/455401/fastboot-hangs-but-adb-works/455402#455402). Only the port closest to the back worked for fastboot.